# Перезагрузка измененного списка в телеграмм боте. /restart. pyTelegramBotAPI. Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, бот, python-telegram-bot

Я разработал телеграмм-бот для редактирования списка услуг и их цен с помощью ChatGPT, Python, pyTelegramBotAPI. Мой бот может редактировать цены и количество услуг, а также производить подсчет общей цены. Я добавил команду /restart, которая должна была восстановить исходное состояние моего списка услуг после изменений.

Проблема в том, что команда /restart не работает должным образом. Список услуг не обнуляется,
и бот продолжает использовать измененный список, невзирая на команду /restart.

Мой код ниже:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

# Ваш токен бота
TOKEN = "TOKEN "

# Словарь, содержащий список услуг и их начальных цен и количеств
services = {
    "Услуга 1": {"price_per_unit": 100, "quantity": 0},
    "Услуга 2": {"price_per_unit": 65, "quantity": 0},
    #...
}

# Создание бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

selected_service = {}

markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
buttons = [types.KeyboardButton(service) for service in services.keys()]
markup.add(*buttons)
markup.add(types.KeyboardButton("Подсчет цены"))

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(
         message.chat.id,
        "Выберите услугу для редактирования цены и количества:",
        reply_markup=markup,
    )

@bot.message_handler(commands=["restart"])
def restart(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    selected_service[chat_id] = {}  # Очистка выбранной услуги

    bot.send_message(
        chat_id,
        "Бот был обновлен до начального состояния. Все изменения сброшены.",
        reply_markup=markup,
    )

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text in services.keys())
def edit_price_or_quantity(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    service = message.text

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    price_button = types.KeyboardButton("Изменить цену")
    quantity_button = types.KeyboardButton("Изменить количество")
    finish_button = types.KeyboardButton("Готово")
    markup.add(price_button, quantity_button, finish_button)

    bot.send_message(
        chat_id,
        f"Выберите действие для {service}:",
        reply_markup=markup,
    )

    selected_service[chat_id] = service
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, handle_edit_choice)

def handle_edit_choice(message, selected_action=None):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_selected_service = selected_service.get(chat_id)

    if user_selected_service:
        selected_action = message.text
        if selected_action == "Изменить цену":
            current_price = services[user_selected_service]['price_per_unit']
            formatted_message = (
                f"Текущая цена для '{user_selected_service}': {current_price} грн\n"
                f"Введите новую цену для '{user_selected_service}':"
            )
            bot.send_message(chat_id, formatted_message)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, update_price_or_quantity, user_selected_service, "price_per_unit", selected_action)
        elif selected_action == "Изменить количество":
            current_quantity = services[user_selected_service]['quantity']
            formatted_message = (
                f"Текущее количество для '{user_selected_service}': {current_quantity}\n"
                f"Введите новое количество для '{user_selected_service}':"
            )
            bot.send_message(chat_id, formatted_message)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, update_price_or_quantity, user_selected_service, "quantity", selected_action)
        elif selected_action == "Готово":
            start(message)
        else:
            formatted_message = "Некорректный выбор. Выберите действие из клавиатуры."
            bot.send_message(chat_id, formatted_message)
    else:
        formatted_message = "Сначала выберите услугу для редактирования цены."
        bot.send_message(chat_id, formatted_message)

def update_price_or_quantity(message, service, parameter_name, selected_action):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    if service in services:
        if message.text.isdigit():  # Проверка, является ли текст числовым
            try:
                new_value = int(message.text)
                services[service][parameter_name] = new_value

                formatted_message = f"'{parameter_name}' для '{service}': {new_value} грн\n"
                formatted_message += f"Редактировать еще раз '{service}':"

                bot.send_message(chat_id, formatted_message)
                bot.register_next_step_handler(message, handle_edit_choice, selected_action)
            except:
                formatted_message = f"Некорректный формат '{parameter_name}'. Введите число.\n"
                formatted_message += f"Редактировать еще раз '{service}':"
                bot.send_message(chat_id, formatted_message)
                bot.register_next_step_handler(message, update_price_or_quantity, service, parameter_name, selected_action)
        elif message.text == "Изменить цену":
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, handle_edit_choice, "Изменить цену")
        elif message.text == "Изменить количество":
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, handle_edit_choice, "Изменить количество")
        else:
            formatted_message = "Некорректный ввод. Введите 'Изменить цену' или 'Изменить количество'."
            bot.send_message(chat_id, formatted_message)
    else:
        formatted_message = f"Выберите следующее действие."
        bot.send_message(chat_id, formatted_message)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "Подсчет цены")
def calculate_total_price(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id

    services_text = []

    for service_name, service_data in services.items():
        price_per_unit = service_data["price_per_unit"]
        quantity = service_data["quantity"]
        service_total = price_per_unit * quantity

        if service_total > 0:
            service_formatted = f"{service_name}\n" \
                                f"Количество: {quantity} шт.\n" \
                                f"Цена за шт.: {price_per_unit} грн/шт.\n" \
                                f"Общая стоимость: {service_total} грн\n"
            services_text.append(service_formatted)

    total_price_formatted = f"\nОбщая сумма: {sum([service_data['price_per_unit'] * service_data['quantity'] for service_data in services.values()])} грн"

    result_message = "\n".join(services_text)
    result_message = f"{result_message}\n\n{total_price_formatted}"

    bot.send_message(chat_id, result_message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Как я могу устранить эту проблему и сделать так, чтобы команда /restart восстанавливала исходное состояние списка услуг и очищала все изменения?

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно понимаете конструкции в Python

Проблема в том, что **services - это словарь**, а значит данная строчка:

```
selected_service[chat_id] = service
```

Передает его здесь по ссылке и изменение

```
selected_service[chat_id][*something*] = 1
```

Будет эквивалентно:

```
service[*something*] = 1
```

Для решения этой проблемы используйте конструкцию:

```
selected_service[chat_id] = dict(service)
```

В таком случае Ваш изначальный словарь не будет изменен и Ваш метод restart будет работать корректно (если, конечно, вы обращаетесь к **selected_service[chat_id]** по коду)